# Safari's <textarea> is not rendering child nodes or entities

Tags: html, textarea, rendering, entities

I am trying to force line wrapping in a textarea tag. Used as a onscreen session log for users.

HTML5, Safari 7.0.5 (OS X 10.5.1).

```
<textarea id="iTest" rows="10" cols="200" style="wrap: [hard|soft|virtual]">
    Line 1<br />Line 2
</textarea>
```

This works under IE9 and displays a textarea with 2 lines. In Safari I get the unescaped unrendered text. That is the output is:

```
"Line 1<br />Line 2"
```

inside the textarea box.

I've tried the CSS wrap attribute with the values show above - all three, no help.

Is there something special with Safari/WebKit or IE/Trident? Is Safari broken? or does IE have special behaviours again?

I need a solution that can use the document.getElementById("iTest").innerHTML setter as I use AJAX to pass data to be displayed in the textarea.

Comment: Also, I tried inserting entities `$lt;`, `&gt;` as a test and the `&...;` came through unaltered.

Answer (score 0):

This must have been a bug or some weird compatibility mode in IE9.  The textarea is supposed to render the full text, and not interpret any html elements.  In other words, the behavior you saw in Safari was correct.

In order to have a line break in the text area, you need to just add a carriage return where you want the line break.  If that doesn't work for your AJAX case,  please update your question with details of how you use the AJAX return value to populate your text area.  You may have luck with using "\r\n" in the JSON to represent the carriage return/line feed.